# Calculate correlation between columns produce error: unsupported operand/ cannot convert the series

Tags: python, correlation

I want to calculate the point biserial correlation between all my columns (continuous) in the data frame and the target variable(binary). I want the results in a list.

My code:

```
corr_list= {}
for column in df:
    corr_list= stats.pointbiserialr(df[column], df['target'])
    print (corr_list)
```

This is the error:

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'float' and 'str'
```

I tried to fix this with float/int, but it's not working:

```
corr_list= {}
for column in df
    x= float(df[column])
    y= float(df['target'])
    corr_list= stats.pointbiserialr(x, y)
    print (corr_list)
```

This is the error:

```
TypeError: cannot convert the series to <class 'float'>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot convert pandas Series object to float object.

Instead, use Series built in method `astype()`:

```
corr_list = {}
y = df['target'].astype(float)
for column in df
    x = df[column].astype(float)
    corr = stats.pointbiserialr(x, y)
    corr_list[column] = corr 
print(corr_list)
```

Comment: Thanks, it works. How can I had to the list the name of the column?

Comment: Modify how you populate the dictionary. Check the edited answer.

Comment: Thanks. How can I change the results to columns output ? It's really hard analyzing it this way.

Comment: Not exactly sure what do you want to achieve. You can convert the dictionary to Series (or DataFrame) as [documented here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.to_dict.html)

Comment: The results is duplicated, each column appear a few times. why is that?

Comment: I don't see your code, can't help you. Make sure you double check your code and copy the example I've provided again if needed.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/221564/discussion-between-raidasgrisk-and-lili).